# iOS - MPMoviePlayerController - controls sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

What are the controls sizes of the iOS native player? (couldn't find it).

These red lines:

[image]

Comment: In case you are planning to hardcode any value you find out about in your application or content, DONT! Apple may and will decide to reskin the player and change the sizes of these elements.

Comment: How can i get these values??? (no hardcoded - promise!)

Comment: There is no documented way to get them and the reasoning is pretty much clear, Apple does not want you to modify or extend the interface of the player. The only proper option is to create your own interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of a tool to discover the view hierarchy and the description of each view in this hierarchy.

Please see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios) on approaches for view hierarchy inspection.

Comment: try CBIntrospector, their screenshots show they display the view sizes.