# iOS - Is there a way to show Autolayout constraints while debugging?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to be able to see the NSLayoutConstraints that I have set between individual UILabels while debugging. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5150186/332248) might help? It's rather about how do inspect the view hierarchy either by string output or by using tools then to see the Constraints directly...

Comment: It looks like Reveal is going to do the trick. Thanks Jens!

Comment: Your welcome. Btw. Upvoting is the way to say thanks on SO. Works on comments too. :-)

Comment: I don't see any arrows next to the comment (read that - http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) ... I only see the up/down arrow next to my question :(

Comment: They only appear when you hover over them with your mouse (next to a comment) But in your link it says you can only upvote when you scored 15 points. Since you just started you only have 1 and therefore can't upvote (I guess)... Nevermind. Hope Reveal is helping anyways...

Comment: Thanks Jens! Yeah, helps a lot. Sorry that I can't upvote you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Xcode 6, there is a way to show the constraints while debugging.

1. Run your application on either simulator or device.
2. Select 'Debug View Hierarchy' which appears between 'Step out' and 'Simulate Location'[image]
3. Select the control that you want to view the constraints

[image]

4. Select 'Show Constraints'

[image]

Result:

[image]