# presentViewController not presenting view, but viewDidLoad(…) does get called

Tags: ios, user-interface

I've been looking at other users with similar issues, but none of those suggestions seem to work. My issue is that I am working on an iPad app and at one point in the workflow, the user can spawn a modal dialog. However, the dialog never shows up (the screen does darken indicating something is happening).

I spawn the dialog like this:

```
ASecondaryImplantChooserDialog* secondaryImplantChooserDialog = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ASecondaryImplantChooserDialog"];

[secondaryImplantChooserDialog setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[secondaryImplantChooserDialog setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];

[self presentViewController:secondaryImplantChooserDialog animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I should note that the class name and storyboard identifier are the same by design.

The viewDidLoad(…) method of secondaryImplantChooserDialog does get called, but other methods don't (such as viewWillLayoutSubviews). I use the same kind of code to spawn other dialogs in other parts of the app, which leads me to think there's something about the controller's configuration in the storyboard at fault, however, I've copied that configuration from the config of the dialog that does spawn, to no effect. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
Thanks to Yuandra Ismiraldi's suggestion below, I was able to diagnose the view hierarchy. I do see the associated view in the printout. On a hunch, I deleted the view from the storyboard, and made a new one. This addresses the issue.

Comment: try turning off definesPresentationContext ?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to do it. The weird thing about it is that viewDidLoad(…) gets called, but the layout functions don't seem to, which I think means the window is 'off-screen' somewhere, but if so, why?

Comment: Try adding secondaryImplantChooserDialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext; , instead of letting your presented  view controller set the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also present the view controller in `viewDidLoad`, which doesn't work. `viewDidAppear` does work, though you need to be careful that you don't present more than once since it's called more often.

Answer (score 1):

If viewDidLoad is called, then the view is loaded. The question then is what exactly the status of the view controller (is it hidden or perhaps off screen). I recommend you first try to inspect the view controller hierarchy as described in this thread [How do I inspect the view hierarchy in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios)

Comment: Yes. This is a good idea. Or get a tool like [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com/) or [Reveal App](http://revealapp.com/) - both have free trials available