# Xcode 5/6: View Debugging always grayed out?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

The "Debug / View Debugging" menu is always grayed out for me in Xcode 5 (and 6), even when the target is stopped at a breakpoint.  How do I enable it?

[image: Debug / View Debugging]

Comment: Can you supply an image to illustrate what you mean? As your question isn't really much to go on.

Comment: What about when you're not paused? View debugging pauses the run automatically, so you can't do it if you're already paused.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the "Product" menu. I can't build or run anything.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets, I tried both. Neither works. Does it work for you?

Comment: Then it's probably a bug in Xcode, I'd file a radar

Comment: Has a radar been filed for this? I can't get this feature to work in any of the simulators. I'm using Xcode 6 GM.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For me (Xcode 6 Beta and Beta two) the View Debugging options are only enabled in 32bit simulators (e.g. works when I use 'iPhone 5' but not when I am using 'iPhone 5s')

Comment: Thanks, that was it. If anyone cares about this problem, you can duplicate radar #17375193.

Comment: It also works for me in 64-bit if I start a completely new project with Xcode 6.0. The old project still only works on 32-bit.

Comment: Same behavior in the GM. Not documented anywhere, of course.

Comment: Indeed, only on iOS 8 for 32bits builds

Comment: Cannot get it to work at all in Xcode 6.0.1 with a keyboard extension written in Swift. Tried every simulator from 4s up to 6, all iOS8 obviously.

Comment: It works on 64-bit simulators if you add arm64 to the `Valid Architecture` settings of your target and if you set the `Architectures` settings to "Standard architectures" (includes arm64)

Answer (score 25):

I believe that the Capture View Hierarchy feature is only available when the target is running iOS 8.

In Xcode 6 (beta 2) the schema popup on the toolbar lets you choose the type of simulated device. For me the fixed devices show up three times. This is because I have three environments available: iOS 7, iOS 7.1 and iOS 8. However, this information is missing from the popup, which appears to be an Xcode 6 bug. The bottom group of devices, including "Resizable iPhone" and "Resizable iPad", are running iOS 8. If you use one of these devices the View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy menu item becomes available.

However, iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices… lets you edit the device names to make them more informative.

Note that this crashes for me every time I try to view a hierarchy that is using a UIMapView.

Answer (score 11):

Also make sure that view debugging isn't disabled in your current scheme's run options:

[image: Xcode settings for view debugging]

Xcode 6.1 still has the limitations about view debugging only working on 32 bit devices (iPhone 5 or older) and on iOS 8, though.

Comment: Thanks, this check box was disabled in my case. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well, but I could see it enabled when I create a new project using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. people just guess it's targeted for iOS.
On my OS X 10.8 MacBook pro with Xcode 5.1.1, sometimes the menu its always disabled for a project for Mac OS X.

On my OS X 10.9 Mac mini with Xcode 5.1.1, it is enabled.

Looks to me a bug..

Answer (score 0):

Another option for view debugging is iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer:
https://github.com/glock45/iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer

Answer (score 0):

1. **Test environment :** Xcode version 6.1 (6A1052d)

   **Test project:** My project ( support for 64- bit and iOS deployment target is iOS6)

   **Test results:** The View Debugging options are only enabled in iPhone5 with iOS8
2. **Test environment :** Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)

   **Test project :** [Xcode-ViewDebugging](http://github.com/tutsplus/Xcode-ViewDebugging) ( supports 64- bit and iOS  deployment target is iOS8)

   **Test results :** The View Debugging options are enabled in all simulators with iOS8
3. So be sure that it must be iOS8, but still do not know the specific rules

Answer (score 0):

By adding support for 64bit (arm64) in your target, View Debugging is enabled for 64bit devices (iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus)

In your target build settings make sure under Architectures that standard architectures is checked $(ARCHS_STANDARD), and under Valid Architectures you have arm64.