# Xcode 6 View Debugging not available

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios8, xcode6

I'm debugging my project and moving it to support iOS 8. Among many other problems I've noticed that Xcode 6's new feature of view debugging is not available in the Debug Bar and is also not available in the Applications menu bar.

Is there a build setting for this feature?

[image: The Debug Bar, the view debugging icon should be visible to the left of the right most "arrow" icon]

[image: The Debug Menu Bar, view debugging is greyed out]

Comment: Are you targeting an iOS 8 device?

Comment: I'm targeting the iPhone 6 on iOS simulator. The application on a whole is not targeting iOS 8 it needs to support iOS 5.1.1

Comment: I tried changing my iOS Deployment Target to 8 to see if that would change anything and it did not. View Debugging is still unavailable

Comment: Sounds like you might be a victim of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040322/xcode-5-6-view-debugging-always-grayed-out

Comment: Okay that might help, I'm on XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317). Isn't that the current released version via the app store? If not I'll be reinstalling. Googling the version as I type

Comment: So this bug made it into the released version of Xcode according to wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Versions_compare_table

Answer (score 5):

Two things worth mentioning about view debugging:

a) Yes, there is a setting in Xcode to enable/disable view debugging per scheme. Edit your current scheme (Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...) and check the 'Run > Options' section.

[image: Setting in Xcode to enable/disable view debugging]

b) Even in Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d), two prerequisites need to be fulfilled for view debugging to work (at least in my experience):

- App needs to be running on a 32 bit device (iPhone 5 or older)
- App needs to be running on iOS 8 or newer

View debugging worked for me on both, actual devices and in the simulator (although it works more reliable for me on the simulator).

Comment: For a specific project, I'm noticing view debugging is only present when running a 32 bit sim.  In others, I have no problem running it with a 64 bit sim.  There must be some other variable at play here - any idea?

Answer (score 2):

view debugging is only available after you run the application.Right now they are disable.
Just run your app then go to view debugging[image: Here is screenshot]

Comment: I was running the application while taking those screenshots

Comment: which version of os is installed in ur mac.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 11.5 & 11.6:**

**Swift 5.2:**

Edit scheme -> Run -> Info -> check the button `Debug Executable`

Now run the project. We can debug now ..!!!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's Working on Xcode 6 with iPhone 5s simulator