# Xcode 6.1 can't find 'debug view hierarchy' button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

My Xcode version is 6.1. I can find 'debug view hierarchy' button in a new created project,  but not with my old project(and the menu item 'capture view hierarchy are always grayed out).

My old project is 32-bit only mac project(not ios) with no arc. my code written mixed with objective-c and c++.

Anyone knows why my old project can't use view debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it doesn't work on 32-bit Mac App Project

Answer (score 12):

Doesn't work on iOS 7. It only works with iOS 8+ simulator.

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 6.2, it is not in the Debug Area, it is in a Debug Navigator:

[image]

Then, select View UI Hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

already answered it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29327564/1194441

And the text:
By adding support for 64bit (arm64) in your target, View Debugging is enabled for 64bit devices (iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus)

In your target build settings make sure under Architectures that standard architectures is checked $(ARCHS_STANDARD), and under Valid Architectures you have arm64.

Answer (score 1):

Click to run your project then you can see the button `Debug view hierarchy` in the `Debug Area`. The relate document [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html)