# Xcode - can't find Debug View Hierarchy button

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode6

I can't find the Debug View Hierarchy button in Xcode.

I've read this:

[Xcode 6.1 can't find 'debug view hierarchy' button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728940/xcode-6-1-cant-find-debug-view-hierarchy-button)

and launched my app on the iOS8 simulator but still no luck. Something to do with the Architectures perhaps?

Here's what I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Are you running on an iOS 8 device? If you aren't then it won't work

Comment: On the iOS 8 iPhone 6 simulator.

Comment: @DanielGalasko that's incorrect. it works on simulator.

Comment: @DanielGalasko Just a clarification, if you meant that it has to be a device then it is incorrect, it can work on device or simulator. But if you meant an iOS8 device as in the device must has iOS8, then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left side of the debugger, in the toolbar below:

[image: Debug View hierarchy]

It is the second icon from the right in the image. It might be black or greyed out depending on whether Xcode is in focus or not.

It works fine on device and simulator. Either click it to break or break using a breakpoint/debugger and use it.

Comment: Thanks but to clarify - the reason I can't find it is because the button does not appear there.

Comment: The symbol will not show until after running and having the app launch either in the simulator or phone. Is is still not showing after running the app?

Comment: I made some changes to the Architectures and I can see it now, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Check to see if accidentally you have disables User Interface debugging. You can find this option in Edit scheme, check out the screenshot:

[image]

Then this button will be back:

[image]

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

In your **scheme settings**, accessible via Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme, there  is an option called **debug executable**,
Enable it to make the debug buttons available

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tibin Thomas and @Khaled Barazi. The **Debug View Hierarchy** button only appears if you have

1. checked the **Debug executable** box and
2. run your app on the simulator.

By the way, in Xcode 13.1, the button have already become as following icon

[image]