# Where is debug view hierarchy button in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode12

I saw the same question here: [Xcode - can't find Debug View Hierarchy button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657634/xcode-cant-find-debug-view-hierarchy-button) . But it doesn't work in Xcode 12. This button looks like carved. And I can't find this option in editor.

How open debug view hierarchy in Xcode 12?

My xcode:
[image]

I expected:

[image]

Comment: I found the answer in your linked question: Make sure that "View Debugging - Enable user interface debugging" is enabled in the "Run" scheme under "Options"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are running the project? It's still there (Xcode 12.0.1):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It also could happen if you did not enable `Debug executable` option on Scheme edition window. A shortcut for open this is:  ⌘ ⇧ **,**

[image: Edit Scheme Window]

Comment: Argh! First time I picked up a client project where Run was set to Release!