# Unidentified box appears at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es-2.0

This one has me completely stumped. I'm resurrecting a graphics project that I did a little over a year ago in iOS 6 and XCode 4. It worked just fine then. Now I'm trying to run it in iOS 7 and XCode 6. My UIViewController looks like this in the storyboard, which is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

But when I run it, I get this. Notice the strange blue and gray box in the bottom center. I have no idea where this comes from!

[image]

I have literally commented out every line of code, so that the implementation file looks like this:

```
#import "PerspectiveViewController.h"

@implementation PerspectiveViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

The interface file is like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface PerspectiveViewController : GLKViewController

// all of the outlets for the controls, but nothing else

@end
```

Does anyone have any idea where that blue and gray box is coming from? There used to be a UITabBarController involved, but I stripped that out. Maybe there is still something left over?

Comment: Have you tried using Apple's UIView inspection tool, or something like Reveal? i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this. This solved my issue. If you post this as a an answer, I'll accept it. Looks like there was a remnant of the UITabBar with a reference to two separate images that were much too large. Easy fix, once I knew where to look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to debug views which you don't expect to be there is by using a tool like Xcode's UIView inspection or Reveal. You can see many more examples and some discussion in this question: [How do I inspect the view hierarchy in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios)

Comment: Looks like there was a remnant of the UITabBar with a reference to two separate images that were much too large. Thanks!