# Weird UIStoryBoard Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, xcode7.3

I am trying to put a `UIImageview` on top, and two `UITextFields` follow underneath it. All are confined with Constraints, and it was working fine a few hours ago. But Something weird is happening now. I run the app, and the View comes around but there is no `ImageView` or where the `UITextFields` were supposed to be, they aren't visible there anymore, but when i click on that position, the Keyboard pops out, which means there are both `UITextFields` here but somehow can't be seen. I've cleaned, deleted derived data etc but nothing is coming around. Any idea?

So here are two snapshots that explains that the image "launchSplash" is coming over the other elements. How could I make it go back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try inspecting your views http://stackoverflow.com/a/26052806/1806119 you haven't provide enough information

Comment: Provide some screenshots and/or share the storyboard file/project.

Comment: How are we supposed to help with such a vague description of your setup? You will need to post a **lot** more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping me out here, it was a mere change or hierarchy of in my Storyboard UI. I didn't put them in the order required and was experiencing this bug. Here are attached snapshots of the new working order of elements in my View Controller.

[image]

[image]

Thanks again for all your help, Inspecting sure is helpful and fun :)