# Tab bar not showing on sub pages during runtime

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

[image]I have a UITabBarController with 4 tabs, suppose A,B,C and D. I have a table view in page A. On clicking on any of the rows, E page opens.
The problem is that on creating show segue from view controller A to E, the tab bar appears below in E in storyboard, whereas during runtime no tab bar is visible on E. Please could anyone help me out in this.

EDIT :

I can add tab bar item to tab bar of subview as below:

[image]

This is the view hierarchy :
[image]

Note :  I want to the tab bar of the main A-D tabs in all sub pages of A-D

Comment: Are you sure it's **Show** segue and not **Present Modally**?

Also, are your tableviewcontrollers embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: @netigger Yes its show segue and its embedded in UINavigationController. Back button is coming properly on page E too.

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand your question. If you already embedded the table view controller inside UINavigationController, it should be no problem to push (by using *Show* segue) E to it and the tab bar should be visible unless you uncheck the "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" in your navigation controller.

Comment: Maybe you can debug view hierarchy? And show how that looks?

Comment: Can you show your storyboard?

Comment: @bubuxu  "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" is unchecked

Comment: @netigger how do I debug view hierarchy?

Comment: @Amanpreet I have added the storyboard

Comment: I think its not a tab. Its a bottom bar of navigation controller. Just try to to hide it the bottom bar of navigation controller. Because as per my opinion tab bar's usual behavior is that it will show only sub pages of it not in views that are not part of it(i.e View E is not part of tab bar).

Comment: @Amanpreet Bottom bar of navigation controller is set to none

Comment: Can you set a tab bar item on this bottom bar?

Comment: @Dia debug view hierarhcy like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26052806/897465

Comment: @Amanpreet yes i am able to set tab bar item

Comment: @netigger it doesn't show tab bar in debug view hierarchy

Comment: I want to see. If you don't mind can you update the image. And One more thing is that default behavior that you can see tab in E view because its not usual thing.

Comment: @Amanpreet I have taken a new view controller as E and set its tab bar item to favourites. I have updated image in my question

Comment: Strange thing!! Please check the bottom bar is "none" ? Or its property changed for this view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to show you two images in different conditions. Maybe it's not a answer but will help you in some manner.

!) I have tab bar controller connected with navigation controller. That Tab bar has two items. "Top Rated" view has a button that connected to other view controller. Check right hand side `attribute` section for this `bottom bar` is `none`.

[image]

2)Same condition for second image but this time I changed the bottom bar option of this view controller(check attribute section). Now the view controller has tab bar item.

[image]

But this will not show in run time because this is not connected with tab bar controller. One more thing you can easily put tab bar item on new view controller that are not connected with navigation and tab bar controller, but when you run it will not there.

**Updated:**

This will help you. Try to set navigation inside of tab bar controller. Give tab bar item to navigation controller. Like:

[image]

**Output is:**

[image]

**When button clicked:**

[image]

In that manner you can tab bar in all views.

**Update 2:**

Here I have Navigation then Home view then the above process with tab bar controller and its working fine.

[image]

Updated Output:

[image]

When button clicked:

[image]

Comment: My tab bar shows in storyboard on all subviews too. It just doesn't show on runtime. I want to the tab bar of the main A-D tabs in sub pages of all pages of A-D

Comment: @Dia please check the updated section of answer. May be this is thing that you want.

Comment: Its working but its leaving empty space of a navigation bar below the actual navigation barand then displaying the contents

Comment: I guess its due to use of navigation controller twice. How do I overcome that?

Comment: Use pattern like Tab bar controller -> Navigation Controller -> View controller. Do not use navigation as a initial view controller.

Comment: But i need to use it to go back to home page

Comment: @Dia check the update 2 section of answer here I used navigation as initial view controller.

Comment: My structure is exactly the same but on runtime it leaves an empty space on top. Is that the same in your case?

Comment: On "forgot your login details" page is it working fine after update 2?

Comment: Yes Do you need its output?

Comment: Please check your attributes of navigation controller. May be there will be some problem.

Comment: Thanks for accepting if it useful for you please do not forget to give up votes :)

Comment: I checked.. Its an empty space below the navigation bar still.. Can you give any color to the forgot details page and check please

Comment: @Dia check the updated output. I have no issue. Please check carefully all attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will check it.. must have missed something out for sure