# How to animate a UIView from within a class file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am working on an application where the user clicks to add a station, from there a pop-up window will appear asking the user for the appropriate information, the UIView will be animated but I am having trouble getting it to work from insides its separate file.

Here is the code from the Animations.swift file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Animations: UIView {

    func animatePopUpIn(view: UIView, controller: UIViewController) {

        controller.view.addSubview(view)
        view.center = center

        view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        view.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            controller.view.alpha = 1
            controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

    }
```

}

Here is the code for the StationController.swift file.

```
import UIKit

class StationController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var addStationView: UIView!
    var animation = Animations()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Stations"
    }

    @IBAction func addStationTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        animation.animatePopUpIn(view: addStationView, controller: self)
        print("Displayed Pop Up")
    }


    @IBAction func dismissPopUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    }


}
```

For some reason upon tapping addStationTapped nothing appears, any help would be great for I am fairly new to working with classes in this manner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need this class?

Comment: What size does view (presented) have? How do you create it in IB? I'm almost sure it has zero-size.

Comment: You can use new Xcode tool for UI debugging - view hierarchies.

Comment: There are several times when I will be needing to animate a popup. I would rather have some sort of class or function that does it automatically by passing in the appropriate parameters that way I don't have to rewrite the same code over and over again

Comment: As for the size of the view, It is sized inside of the main storyboard. I created the outlet addStationView to reference that.

Comment: You can create `static func` in `Animations` or extension for `UIView` or `UIViewController` in this case.

Comment: Can you place breakpoint before `UIView.animatite()` func and check size there?

Comment: Post about better UI debug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052806/1980246

Comment: Sure, the size is (325.0, 172.9)

Comment: What about it's position and background color?

Comment: Center position and white background color, but it has elements inside it such as a label and UITextField

Comment: first of all you should change background colors to make it more visible. Use red for example.

Answer (score 0):

One more better way is to do this is by making seperate viewcontroller and add it as popover . you can use third party class or manually add view controller as pop . if you want to add it manually then i can help.