# Navigation icon is not showing in ios11 with xcode9?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, xcode9

I have installed my existing application in ios11 using xcode8 the navigation bar icons are displaying as expected when app is run using xcode9 the navigation bar icons are not showing but click actions are working fine. any icons in Navigation bar are missing while navigating from one controller to another controller.

Comment: Think you need to work on safe area that is introduced on xcode 9  Here you may find some clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9

Answer (score 0):

If the navigation icons are not showing, but the interaction is still exists and works properly, it seems, that the problem is with image of the BarButtonItem. You can do next:

1) Try to set a system icon for BarButtonItem
2) Look at assets and fill all three resolutions (1, @2x, @3x)
3) Check the color of BarButtonItem
4) Check [View Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me and it was related to the ViewController segue properties. The segue kind was set to "Show Detail(e.g. Replace)" and changing it to Show(e.g. Push) did the trick. This is very weird because it used to work well on previous versions of Xcode but not on Xcode 9.3

Hope that helps!

Main Story board pics:

change the "kind" attribute from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]