# iOS: Constraints behave different on simulator and physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, constraints, simulator

I want a CollectionView to arrange under a TextView without gap.

I'm programmatically creating the TextView, attaching this to TopLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor and attach the topAnchor of an existing CollectionView to the bottom of the TextView.

```
collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Using this line, it works fine on - I assume - every simulator. But on a physical device (iPhone 5 right now), the CollectionView has a gap to the textview. The gap is maybe the height of the textview.

[image]

If I change the constraint to attaching the CollectionView to the topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor - which is nonsense - its exactly the opposite behaviour. Than the gap is in the simulator and not on the device.

`collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`

Added image of debugging the views:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The simulator and device are the same model and iOS version??

Comment: It's an physical iPhone 5 (latest 10.3.3) and an iPhone 5 simulator (10.3.1). But I tried several simulators with different versions, latest too, without differences.

Comment: I believe you should set the **headerReferenceSize** of your **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**. You can do it in code, or interface builder, choose what better suites you

Comment: did my suggestion helped you?

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt help. This value is zero by default if not set. I tried setting the headerRefSize to -50. It shifts up, but on both iOS. Then it's overlapping the navigationBar on the physical device.

Comment: There is a button in the debugger that shows you all views and their size and position. Use it! See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052806/2830676

Comment: See my updated post. The collectionView is indeed pinned to the textView. The gap is within the collectionView...but the insets of the cell are correct with x: 10 and y: 5. I can't find more. It's just flying there...

Comment: I really believe that you find the correct field in the flow layout!! Try there all values to 0