# The viewWillAppear of the UITabBarController is always executed twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

When I log in successfully with a third party and then jump to the UITabBarController, the `viewWillAppear` of the UITabBarController is always executed twice.

This is the code of jumpping to the UITabBarController. TTabBarVC inherited from UITabBarController.

```
TTabBarVC *vc = [TTabBarVC new];
KLNavigationController *nc = [[KLNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
UIViewController *oldRootVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[UIView transitionFromView:oldRootVC.view toView:nc.view duration:.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = nc;
}];
```

Comment: What about the viewDidLoad? Is it called twice too?

Comment: it is called one about the ViewDidLoad

Comment: I assume you meant viewDidLoad is called once. If that is so, i think there is some view which is active on top of the tabbar controller. Something like alert, popup or maybe aven a viewController. I suggest you go through the code again and verify. You code seems fine and does the job. I tried it and it does work. viewWillAppear is not being called twice. Try printing the window's view hierarchy when viewWillAppear is being called.

Comment: How I print the window's view hierarchy when viewWillAppear is being called.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on viewWillAppear. Then check "Debug View Hierarchy" in Xcode. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios)