Black screen when running app in iOS simulator in Xcode
I am new to iOS programming and learning how to use UIKit in the swift project. I created a simple project to display a text message using UIKit on an iOS simulator (iOS 16) in xcode. Below is my ContentView.swift and testApp.swift files:
ContentView.swift
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Create a UIWindow instance
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if window == nil {
            print("Window is nil.")
        } else {
            print("Window is not nil.")
        }
        let viewController = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        if window?.rootViewController == nil {
            print("Root view controller is not set.")
        } else {
            print("Root view controller is set.")
        }
        if let rootView = window?.rootViewController?.view {
            print("Root view hierarchy:")
            print(rootView.subviews)
        }
        if let viewController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
            print("Status label text: \(viewController.statusLabel.text ?? "Not set")")
        }      
        return true
    }
}


testApp.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    public var statusLabel = UILabel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Configure status label
        statusLabel.text = "This is an example"
        statusLabel.textAlignment = .center
        statusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        statusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(statusLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            statusLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            statusLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

It builds without any error but when the app opens in the simulator I get a black scrren without any text. The debug messages Window is not nil. and Root view controller is set. aare printed. The Root view hierarchy: doesn't contain UILabel and statusLabel text.
Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here? Is the statusLabel not initialzed correctly? I also see message [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 3 in the log.
Thanks in advance
P.S: i am using xcode 15.0.1, Destination iPhone, SDK iOS, minimum deployments 16.0, Excluded architectures is empty. Please let me know if I missed anything

You can use Debug View Hierarchy https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052806/1801544 and see if you have the view controller there etc. Might want to change the background colors of some items?

HI @Larme, when I open 'Debug View Hierarchy', it's empty (blank screen) (simulator is running)

The name ContentView.swift makes me think you have accidentally created a SwiftUI project but then you've tried to use UIKit in it.

Also the code you are using is way outdated. You need a newer tutorial.

@matt, thanks for the hint. Yes, I accidently created SWiftUI project in Xcode. Now I am using SwiftUI package and it's working.

Accidently created SwiftUI project in Xcode and tried using UIKit. However, when used SwiftUI instead of UIKit it's working.
Thanks @matt (in comments) for pointing out this
